# Fastboot command taking so much time

Tags: android, command, flash-memory, fastboot

I'm working on some root stuff for my swipe android tab. While I reached at fastboot mode, I have fired fastboot oem command from my Windows terminal it taking more time to accomplish.

The command is

```
fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0
```

Here is my problem:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated...